# How to use void(class) in java?

Tags: java, class

I got a class called Location:

```
public class Location {

    public int x,y;

    void Location(int x, int y){
    }
}
```

A class called Soldier:

```
public class Soldier {

   String id;

   Location l1 = new Location();

   void Soldier(String id, Location l1);
}
```

When i call:

```
Soldier s1 = new Soldier();

s1.Soldier("Sniper",(100,200))
```

From another class, it said an error "no suitable method found". Please help!

I am not good at English nor Java so I'm sorry for my unclear question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Three main problems:

1. You're defining your constructors incorrectly: Remove `void` in front of them:

   ```
   public class Location {

       public int x,y;

       Location(int x, int y){   // *** No `void`
       }
   }
   ```

   (And the same on `Soldier`.)

   With the `void` there, they aren't constructors, they're *methods*.

   You might also want them to be `public`, but that depends on how you want to use them.
2. Your `Soldier` constructor defines that it takes a string and a `Location`. You're not giving it that. You probably wanted to create a `Location`:

   ```
   s1.Soldier("Sniper", new Location(100,200))
   // ------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
3. Your `Soldier` constructor is invalid:

   ```
   void Soldier(String id, Location l1); // Invalid
   ```

   You have a `;` after it and no constructor body. Instead, you probably wanted to have a body there that uses the arguments:

   ```
   Soldier(String id, Location l1) {
       this.id = id;
       this.l1 = l1;
   }
   ```

You might also want to remove the initializer on this field in `Soldier`:

```
Location l1 = new Location();
```

e.g., just

```
Location l1;
```

...since we (now) have `Soldier` using its arguments to set that up (thanks to #3 above).

Answer (score 0):

```
Location l1 = new Location();
```

Above is wrong.

Instance variable initializer like this :

```
Location l1;

void Soldier(String id, Location l1){

   s1.Soldier("Sniper", new Location(100,200));

}
```

You have to create a instance of Location class.

Do like this.

Comment: Well, that's *part* of it.

Comment: Sorry ? Didn't get you.

Comment: Not really. The location inside `Soldier` is instantiated (incorrectly).

Answer (score -1):

first thing you need to learn is **camelCase** 
**2:** your location class has a method name as constructor name, violates java programming conventions 
**3:** 
**learn followings : class, objects, constructor, methods, inheritance**

class Location {

```
public int x, y;

void printLocation(String loc) {
    System.out.println("Location: " + loc);
}
```

}

public class Soldier extends Location{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Soldier s1 = new Soldier();
    s1.printLocation("Syria");
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know why some one gave me -ve voting huh